# How to make the entire page in flutter scrollable

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll

I want to make the entire page in flutter scrollable, while the height in each element inside remains dynamic.
Now the two `Expanded` elements have fixed height and are vertically scrollable - I want to make them extend to their regular height and be able to scroll down to the next element.

```
body: Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(),
        IntrinsicHeight(   //This is fixed height and doesn't move
          child: Text(),
        ),
        new Divider(height: 0.1),
        Text(),
        Expanded(          //This is now vertically scrollable in its own box
            child: Text()
        ),
        Expanded(          //This is now vertically scrollable in its own box
            child: Text()
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

I tired several versions of wrapping the first column in `SingleChildScrollView` but for some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you explain the error that occurs if you wrap your Column Widget with a SingleChildScrollView?

Comment: no error, just blank page (except for the AppBar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. Wrap your `Column()` inside `IntrinsicHeight()` widget,

Refere `IntrinsicHeight` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html)

Refere `SingleChildScrollView` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html), this widget is used for **Scrolling the Widget.**.

```
return Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: IntrinsicHeight(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Try',
          ),
          IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Text(
              'Done',
            ),
          ),
          new Divider(height: 0.1),
          Text(
            'data',
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              'Okk',
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              'Yes',
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your column with a SingleChildScrollView(), so select Column than wrap it with a widget witch is SingleChildScrollView()

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your **Column** widget using **IntrinsicHeight** widget. Then wrap **IntrinstHeight** with **SingleChildScrollView**.

This work fine for me

```
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: IntrinsicHeight(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("tes"),
          IntrinsicHeight(   //This is fixed height and doesn't move
            child: Text("tes"),
          ),
          new Divider(height: 0.1),
          Text("tes"),
          Expanded(          //This is now vertically scrollable in its own box
              child: Text("tes")
          ),
         Expanded(          //This is now vertically scrollable in its own box
              child: Text("tes")
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Note: Put the code inside Scaffold body